# ¿Que código de servidor retornar, en caso de que un recurso exista y no se pueda crear?

Tags: http, cabeceras-http, server

Resulta que tengo un formulario el cual envía datos y guarda los registro en base de datos.

Quisiera saber que código http debo retornar en la cabecera de la respuesta que identifique que el recurso ya existe y por lo tanto no se puede crear.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Como no tengo la reputación suficiente para comentar, te lo escribo aquí. Puede que esta [pregunta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists) te ayude.

Comment: ¿Es un servicio RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que intentases devolver el resultado de la operación como parte de la respuesta y que mantuvieras el código 200 de petición con éxito. Los códigos de respuesta de HTTP tratan de dar información sobre que ha ocurrido con la petición HTTP, no comunicar el resultado de la operación realizada por el servidor.

Citando el RFC de HTTP:

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the
> client seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request,
> the server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition. These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the user.

Lo que quiere decir que indican al cliente que ha cometido un error y dan información sobre si el error temporal (reintentando podría funcionar) o es permanente (por ejemplo una petición mal formada).

Dicho esto, de elegir un código existente a retornar elegiría [409: Conflict](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.10)